# How to check for type equality when comparing types with optional fields in conditional type

Tags: typescript

Take the following TypeScript code:

```js
interface Elephant {
  id: string;
  name: string;
  trunk?: number;
}

interface Fish {
  id: string;
  name: string;
  gills?: number;
}

type MyCondition<Animal> = Animal extends Elephant
  ? "Elephant!"
  : Animal extends Fish
  ? "Fish!"
  : "Not Fish or Elephant";
```

In this case `MyCondition<Fish>` would be `"Elephant!"`, because the *required* types for `Fish` extend the required types for `Elephant`.

How do I check for strict equality, checking that the type `Animal` matches `Elephant` or `Fish` exactly, including optional types?

Answer (score 0):

You can check if `Animal` still extends `Elephant` after making all their properties required:

```js
type MyCondition<Animal> = Required<Animal> extends Required<Elephant>
  ? "Elephant!"
  : Required<Animal> extends Required<Fish>
  ? "Fish!"
  : "Not Fish or Elephant";
```

This doesn't make the properties on the original types required, it's just used here for the `extends` check.